# Exception when using Hibernate Spatial with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a simple Postgres (9.x) test table with a point geometry, when I retrieve the record from the database I get the exception

```
org.geolatte.geom.codec.WktDecodeException: Wrong symbol at position: 1 in Wkt: (53.198691,5.802703)
```

What am I missing? I inserted the record by SQL inside pgAdmin `insert into geometry_test values (1, '(53.198691,5.802703)' );`

I looked for tutorials / info, but only found really old ones :(

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry_test
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('geometry_test_id_seq'::regclass),
    location point,
    path path,
    polygon polygon
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: I believe hibernate spatial should be used with postgis and those should be geometry columns, not point, path, or polygon.

Answer (score 0):

The question that should be asked is "whats the purpose?" I didnt need spatial queries (PostGIS) and decided to write my own UserType for point, path and polygon fields. I only needed to store LAT / LONG values and already had a custom field / dialect for JSONB type

*) Note PostGIS doesnt support these fields either